# Cannot profile test in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, profile

I have a test that is taking a very long time to run when it is run alone.

I tried to profile it by right-clicking on it and selecting "Profile".  When I do that, it runs the test, opens a new window with a `.vsp` extension, then it shows an error window with the following message:

> File contains no data buffers

Googling around for this, I find several posts but they are quite out of date.  (One 3 years ago says .Net Core does not support profiling).

**What can I do to be able to profile my Unit Test?**

Note: My test project is `netcoreapp3.1` and it is testing a `netstandard2.0` project.  I am running using NUnit 3.12.0 and NUnit3TestAdapter 3.15.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of the test console gives a hint:

> ** IMPORTANT ** Profiling .NET Core tests requires full PDB's. Be sure to set Debug information level to Full on each project to be profiled.

You need to put something like

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>    
</PropertyGroup>
```

in any relevant project file or in the Directory.Build.props file.

Also make sure that you have an up-to-date test SDK. I also needed to set the "Processor Architecture for AnyCPU projects" to "Auto".